# How to change table monitoring setting

Tags: oracle, database-administration

I'm working on improving Oracle tables' performances.

The table that I have been working on created with 'monitoring' and 'logging' clause. These two, decreasing performance of query and I need to change monitoring to nomonitoring(without dropping tables).

*This is working well:*

```
alter table some_table nologging
```

*But to alter monitoring to nomonitoring I use;*

```
alter table some_table nomonitoring
```

query executes without any errors but there is no change in table structure.

I've been researching on internet for days and also as I saw here there is no such topic for my specific problem.

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: How are `monitoring` and `logging` affecting performance exactly?

Comment: I have amount of tables with millions of rows. One simple ```select``` query returns in 2 or 2,5 minutes with ```logging``` and ```monitoring```. Without ```logging``` and ```monitoring``` it's reduced to 0-0,5 minutes.

Comment: The difference is not due to monitoring or logging. Did you compare the execution plans?

Comment: yeah, I have compared execution plans.

Comment: And were the plans the same or were they different? I would expect the difference in performance to be explained by a change in execution plan. The `logging` and `monitoring` attributes do not affect `select` statements. `monitoring` isn't a thing any more but even if you go back to 10g, all it monitored was the approximate number of INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE operations for the table since the last time statistics were gathered, so there is no way it could have affected a SELECT statement.

Comment: I meant DML on tables which are created with monitoring or logging. 
The script that I'm trying to tell is(which is before select) ```create table some_table /*+ NOLOGGING */ as select * from other_table``` this script executes faster than ```create table some_table as select * from other_table```

Comment: What? `/*+ NOLOGGING */` isn't even a hint. It's exactly the same as `/*+ KITTENS */`

Comment: Did you mean `create table some_table nologging as select * from other_table`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The monitoring/nomonitoring options are deprecated and are no longer used in Oracle.

[Quote from the Oracle 11.2 manual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/tables.htm#ADMIN11656)

> Formerly, you enabled DBMS_STATS to automatically gather statistics for a table by specifying the MONITORING keyword in the CREATE (or ALTER) TABLE statement. Starting with Oracle Database 11g, the MONITORING and NOMONITORING keywords have been deprecated and statistics are collected automatically. **If you do specify these keywords, they are ignored.**

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

Comment: After I executed ```alter table ... nologging``` I saw that table structure has been changed. But I want to see the change of monitoring to nomonitoring in the table structure.(to be sure)

Comment: `nologging` does **not** change the _structure_ of the table. Only an attribute that controls the logging to the redo log for INSERTs. And as the manual clearly states the `nomonitoring` option is completely **ignored** since Oracle 11 so your second statement simply does nothing.